Create a hole at a position of a vertex
What would be the best and easiest way to create a hole at the position of a selected vertex?
Like this script does:
https://www.scriptspot.com/3ds-max/scripts/create-holes

Bevel vertex then remove it.

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.
